# ngRoute Params url on refresh Not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ngroute

I am using ngRoute in angularjs with node.js and I created an url like 'localhost:3000/user/:id'.
First time when I click on link then it redirect to this page properly and working fine. But when I refresh this url then all path of externally files of css and js getting changed with respect to the Param url.
At first time css file path is '/css/style.css' but after refresh the it becomes '/user/css/style.css'.
I am not sure whats going on. But if I contains the # in url its working fine after refreshing the url.
Below is my route config code and node config code.
ngRoute Provider-

```
$routeProvider.when("/", {
            templateUrl: "/pages/home.html",
            controller: "homeController"
        }).when("/about-us", {
            templateUrl: "/pages/about-us.html",
            controller: "homeController"
        }).when("/users", {
            templateUrl: "/pages/users.html",
            controller: "usersController"
        }).when("/user/:id", {
            templateUrl: "/pages/users.html",
            controller: "usersController"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
```

in node.js

```
var express         = require('express');
var logger          = require('morgan');
var path            = require('path');
var app             = express();
var server          = require('http').createServer(app);

app.use(logger('dev'));

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000); 

app.set('env','development')  ; 
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/pages'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});



    app.all('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('pages/index.html');  
    });

server.on('error', function(err){
    process.exit(1);
}).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('App is running at: '+app.get('port'))
});
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: AngularJS warned you about that, and you chose to ignore the warning by setting `requireBase: false`. Rmove that setting, and do what the router tells you to do: add a base tag to your index.html file. Or use absolute paths rather than relative ones.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to put .htaccess file where all your route redirect to index.html page, by this way your problem will be solved.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule .* / [L,R=302]
```

Try to put this code in .htaccess file and run your application you won't get any issue further, hope this answer will helpful to you.

Comment: If you are using angular routing then why you have set route to get index.html file for all request, i think you have mixed up you routing with express and angular that 's why you are getting this issue, if you are using angular for routing your application then express will be used only for api call, is it clear now or you need some more clearfication

Comment: If you are going to create an app which will use angular as frontend then it should be separate from your express code, it means you must have one root folder which contains 2 folder one for frontend code and second for backend, if you organize your code in this way then you won't get any issue in routing of angular

Comment: I have client and server both on same port thats why I am hitting index.html on every route.

Comment: I think you are running both thing on same port that's why you are getting issue, as i told you before your api must be running on different port and your front-end should be on 80 port or whatever then only you will resolve this issue.

Comment: its not an issue of same port, before I already created application on Angular + node on same port that was working fine. But currently I am having issue and I don't know why. 

When node application gets started and hit the url 'localhost:3000' on the browser then `app.get('*' ...)` middleware will gets hit and it will open the HTML file and from there angular with take care of the routing.

and that concept was working fine in my previous application.

Comment: so if it is correctly working in your case then you can do following change RewriteRule .* / [L,R=302] this rule in your htaccess file as if i understood correct that as in your case index.html file sent from that route you must have to do following change in your htaccess file.  hope this thing will work for you.